# In Android Studio R.java file is empty

Tags: android, android-studio

After opening my project in android studio its showing the following error

```
    "Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Results:processDebugResources'
     > Running /home/gopi/Desktop/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt failed. See output"
```

And also R.java file is empty, I don't know wheather the above error is the reason or not. My R.java is located in src/main/gen/com/example/results

please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

If R is not genereated correctly make sure none of ur java or xml files got error in them.
Try Clean ur project.

Comment: there are no errors in xml files, however in java code setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) shows error message "cannot resolve symbol activity_main".

Comment: R.java file has following lines  " /*___Generated_by_IDEA___*/

package com.example.results;

/* This stub is only used by the IDE. It is NOT the R class actually packed into the APK */
public final class R {
}  "

Comment: Then something is wrong in activity_main.xml, go there and see if u get any errors outputed.

Comment: @JohnnyBroberg, We already know why there is an error with R.layout.activity_main, it's because the generated R can't be found. The culprit may be in activity_main.xml, yes, but there is no guarantee it will be there for sure. Gopi should really double-check all his xml files, not just activity_main.xml

Comment: I started new project.... after running the new project again the same compilation error which I mentioned in question but this time R.java is fine. No errors in xml files and java files but compilation error.......:(:(:(

Answer (score 0):

Really annoying error, I've just had a very similar thing and wanted to re-iterate the importance of checking your XML files for anything odd! In the end mine was an activity that wasn't even in use anymore so going through and 'pruning' your project of obsolete files can help